# PHP: Writing and sorting a file

Tags: php, file, sorting

I'm trying to write a php function that takes the $name and $time and write it to a txt file (no mySQL) and sort the file numerically.

For example:

```
10.2342 bob
11.3848 CandyBoy
11.3859 Minsi
12.2001 dj
```

just added Minsi under a faster time, for example.

If the $name already exists in the file, only rewrite it if the time is faster (smaller) than the previous one, and only write if the time fits within 300 entries to keep the file small.

My forte isn't file writing but I was guessing to go about using the file() to turn the whole file into an array, but to my avail, it didn't work quite like I wanted. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: So what do you want? You did not ask any specific question and did not provide any broken code. Hellooooooo?

Comment: I would like if someone could provide some code, or part of some code that could do this. I've tried reading online tutorials, but they don't suffice.

Comment: Do you have a specific programming question you want an answer to? This is not a free job board; we're here to spread knowledge, answers to specific problems other people will have in the future, not complete individuals' programs. If you want someone to write your code you can post it on a freelance site and pay the programmer.

Comment: @Kevin Duke: it doesn't work here.

Comment: @Dan I imagine this couldn't be that hard to do, but I can't seem to figure out how to accomplish this by reading tutorials. If someone could set me in the right path, I would learn a great deal

Comment: You need nothing but basic PHP syntax and built-in functions you can find from the PHP manual. They're well organized (e.g. string functions, filesystem functions, arrays). If reading online wasn't enough, then you need to buy a book and go through it.

Comment: @Kevin Duke: it is not a right way to **learn**. If you want to **learn** - ask what exactly you cannot do. Decompose your issue into smaller ones and solve them iteratively. When you got in stuck - ask **specific** question.

Comment: I do have plenty of attempts at this code, all which don't produce a desirable output. I didn't post those codes because I don't know which broken code to post and I also feel that posting a random one of my failed attempts won't help the community solve this question any better than if I didn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data sets are small, you may consider using `var_export()`

```
function dump($filename, Array &$data){
    return file_put_contents('<?php return ' . var_export($data, true) . ';');
}

// create a data set
$myData = array('alpha', 'beta', 'gamma');

// save a data set
dump('file.dat', $myData);

// load a data set
$myData = require('file.dat');
```

Perform your sorts using the PHP `array_*` functions, and dump when necessary. `var_export()` saves the data as PHP parsable text, which is why the `dump()` function prepends the string `<?php return`. Of course, this is really only a viable option when your data sets are going to be small enough that keeping their contents in memory is not unreasonable.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a multi dimensional array "$timeArray[key][time] = name" and then sort($timeArray)